# Give the minimum Levenshtein distance to a string that matches the regex

Tags: code-golf, string, regular-expression, edit-distance

Your task, at the moment that you choose to accept it, is to write a program that, when given a string and a PCRE-regex, calculates the minimum Levenshtein distance to another string that matches the regex (fully). All strings, as well as the regexes, should be in the Latin-1 character set.

This is `code-golf`, so the shortest program wins.

The Levenshtein distance (or edit distance) between two strings is the *closeness* of two strings, measured in operations needed to go from one string to another. One operation is one insertion, one deletion, or one substitution.

## Examples

`a, ab+ -> 1` because `ab` matches `ab+` and `levenshtein(a, ab) = 1`

`aaa, .* -> 0` because `aaa` matches

`aaaa, ab+a -> 2` because `aba` matches and `levenshtein(aaaa, aba) = 2`

`abcde, a.?b?.?a -> 2` because `abca` matches and `levenshtein(abcde, abca) = 2`

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861) This looks like a reasonably well-specified challenge, but please note we strongly recommend posting your challenges in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140?answertab=active) before putting them on the main site. This question is currently lacking an [objective scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria), such as [tag:code-golf], and it needs a specification of what regex syntax needs to be supported.

Comment: What regex syntax should be supported?

Comment: In addition to specifying the exact regex syntax (presumably a somewhat minimal one, but how minimal?), it would be desirable to specify the alphabet from which the strings in question are formed--perhaps the lowercase Latin alphabet? (Also note that it's spelled *Leven**sh**tein* distance.)

Comment: Your first example (assuming the good regex is the first one, as the second in the explanation is not valid) seems to suggest that a partial match is enough? If so, it should be stated in the question, and the first example is not good because `a` already partially matches `b*` (`*` means zero to unlimited times, so no `b` matches), so the answer should be `0`

Comment: I edited my question to solve the critical points.

Comment: Are there viable approaches for golfing this other than generating all strings of progressively greater Levenshtein distance until you find one matching the regex?

Comment: @xnor instead of generating strings of progressivly greater levenshtein distance, you can generate all strings of increasing length and go from there, though it would definitely be more bruteforcey.

Comment: I think the alphabet from which the strings are generated should probably be smaller: many of the chars from Latin-1 have a meaning in regex and would pose some escaping problems while taking the inputs.. not even talking about the non-printable ones..

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 114 bytes

```php
for($t=a,$r=INF;$c++<1e8;$t++)preg_match("/^$argv[2]$/",$t)&&($r>$l=levenshtein($argv[1],$t))?$r=$l+$c=0:0;echo$r;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxNCsIwEEDhu5ShJKT0x5WYxuwEN15Aqkzj2AixDWPo9WPFzVt9vOhj7m3c@lxYQDJYAZvz5aTBKdV3tNeQlJKRabq/MTkviuYGyNN63Q3QFBUkWZYC@AjBBFpp/vhEr1n8TTf8gLTbFIICZ9pDq8n5BVjnnHF0D8pY29HWFr8)

This works with a smaller alphabet and some caveats, but passes the test cases:

- current version only works with lowercase letters (will try to improve this point)
- works by bruteforcing all strings using php strings increment
- uses a counter: the result is output if no smaller levenshtein value is found for a matching string after 100000000 (1e8) string increments (this limit was arbitrarily set to have a result in TIO, as 1e9 times out - can be set up to 9e9 with same byte count)
- following these points, current version will not be able to work if the input string is more than 100000000 (or up to 9e9) string increments from "a"

Answer (score 3):

## [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org), 129 bytes

```ruby
require"levenshtein"
def f(s,r,d=1/0,a="`")while(a=a.succ).size-s.size<d
d=[d,Levenshtein.distance s,a].min if a[r]?==a
end
d
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCsIwEETv@YoQL63GVO@G/IB/UApuky0N1FCzraI/H2PBipcdeDOzY@OTJhhSinibfUQx4B0D9RP6IJjDjncFySidPlYHCVpcRPno/YAFaFA0W1sq8i/c0yInx5yunTz/vijn80KwyElCo64@cN9xqGNjtAaGIVc@N43zRHlNgJC8gnZXlWxFsEC1/WffJGS8WXlrHS6GMq1RJpvpDQ)

This fulfills the task if support for lowercase alphabet is enough. Theoretically, this shouldn't have an upper limit on length - the bruteforcing loop stops when the current test string `a` becomes so long that its Levenshtein distance from input `s` can never be smaller than the currently found minimal distance `d`. However, in practice, even the last test case is too big for TIO.